# Add photos and videos to Apple Photos Library through terminal

Tags: terminal, icloud, photos

I know that I can add photos to iCloud through the terminal, but how can I add photos directly to the Apple Photos app through the terminal?

It looks like there are four folders in the "Photos Library.photoslibrary" folder app folder:
`database`, `external`, `originals`, `private`, and `resources`.

But I don't think I can safely add to these without corrupting the database. Can I?

Is there some other CLI-friendly (terminal-based) way to add photos and videos to this database, so that they get quickly shared with all my devices, and uploaded to iCloud as well?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no.

The contents of the `originals` folder are your um.. originals, but they have been renamed to a UUID, and that UUID is registered in the database. The other folders contain other versions as Photos is doing its internal processing and producing derivatives for Moments etc...

If you attempt to just copy files in, they won't be recognised, and certainly won't be uploaded to iCloud Photos. At worst you *will* corrupt the database. The whole thing is enclosed in a package for good reason, to avoid casual fiddling. It doesn't deter the determined ofc..

The UI import process is quite robust, so why not use that instead?

Indeed, perhaps you should question why you want to do this via CLI in the first place. What are you hoping to achieve by being different?

Now, there are some very useful external CLI apps such as https://github.com/RhetTbull/osxphotos which allow queries of the database, and a limited way of adding existing photos to albums, but it doesn't offer import.

Comment: This is actually the worst answer that I've ever received

Comment: Not only is your answer objectively wrong, but it's insulting.

Comment: If its objectively wrong then I invite you to do the research and answer your own question.

Comment: I don't need to prove anything to you.

Comment: If you can explain WHY you want to add photos to the Photos library and database in this unusual way (and not do it the normal way), you might get more information. Adding photos to the Originals folder in the manner you envisage will certainly not create database records for them, nor create the smaller sized versions you see in the other folders, nor assign GUID names. You can find a high-level description of how Photos works here: https://appinitio.medium.com/hey-mac-user-where-are-your-photos-d9056ee4963e , hope it helps you a bit.

Comment: I came looking for this answer, because I want to write a script that will import images to my Photos library unattended. My photos are in a cloud drive, so it takes time to down the image before I can reliably import them into Photos. Thus, my wish for a CLI to Photos so I could script it to run over a weekend without my constant attention.

(I tried just dragging the whole thing over, and it ended up crashing when my system ran out of RAM, because apparently it's not robust enough! )